# View "Variables" and "Frames" tabs for IntelliJ at the same time?

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently, I have two separate tabs: variables and frames, and can only have one open at a time. i like to be able to view the stack trace (frame) and the variables (and possibly even the console) at the same time when I am in debug mode. How do I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to restore the layout on the debugger tab (option is under the setting button to the left)